# Software mitigation for variant 3a (rogue system register read) and variant 4 (speculative store bypass)

Tags: linux, meltdown, spectre, speculative-store-bypass

AFAIK, all mitigable meltdown / spectre variants have software mitigation except for variant 3a and 4. Why is this the case?

For variant 4, a straightforward software mitigation is to place `lfence` before all memory load operations. However, according to section 4.1 of [Spectre is here to stay](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.05178.pdf#subsection.4.1), this will seriously slow things down. I guess this is why it is not implemented in practice.

However, for variant 3a, according to the Mitigation section of the [Intel security advisory](https://software.intel.com/security-software-guidance/software-guidance/rogue-system-register-read), the microcode update ensures that `rdmsr` doesn't speculatively return when we aren't in ring 0 or when `rdmsr` is configured to cause an VM exit. We can have the following software mitigation:

```
if in ring 0 and VM exit bit not set:
    lfence
    rdmsr
else:
    do nothing
```

Does this work? If it does, why isn't it used in practice?